# Intersect of Select Statements based on a particular column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, intersect

I have a Q about INTERSECT clause between two select statements in Sql server 2008.

Select 1 a,b,c .....  INTERSECT  Select 2 a,b,c....

Here, the datasets of the two queries should exactly match to return the common elements.

But, I want only column a of both select statements to match.
If the values of column a in both the queries have same values, the entire row should appear in the result set.

Can i Do that and How ??

Thanks,
Marcus..

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to look at the queries itself. DO they need an INTERSECT, of is it possible to make a join with it

for example.
An INTERSECT looks like this

```
select columnA
from   tableA
INTERSECT
select columnAreference
from   tableB
```

Your result would have all columns that are in BOTH tables.. so a join would be more usefull

```
select columnA
from   tableA a
       inner join tableB b
         on  b.columnAReference = a.columnA
```

If you look into the execution plan you'll see that the INTERSECT will do a left semi join and the inner join will do a, like expected, an inner join. A left semi join isn't something you can tell the query optimizer to do, BUT IT IS FASTER!!!! A left semi join will only return 1 row from the left table, where a normal join will return them all. In this particular case it will be faster.

So an INTERSECT isn't a bad thing which should be eliminated with an INNER JOIN construction, sometimes it will perform even better.
However, to give you the best answer, i will need some more details about your query :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
on t1.col1=t2.col1
```